# Write list to csv with new line without duplicates in iteration

Tags: python, csv

The main problem that I can't write to CSV a list and I got such a result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXT06.png
It shows me a lot of columns. And I need only one column and I don't want any duplicates.
What should I do?

```
import csv

matched_dynamic_pattern = []
matched_static_pattern = []
not_matched = []

with open('processes.csv', 'r') as t1, open('static_patterns.csv', 'r') as t2:
    commands = set()
    reader = csv.DictReader(t1, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        commands.add(row['Command Line'])
    static_patterns = set(t2.read().splitlines())


with open('results1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for command in commands:
        if command.startswith('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type') or command.startswith('"C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Teams\\current\\Teams.exe" --type'):
            matched_dynamic_pattern.append(command)
        else:
            if command not in static_patterns:
                not_matched.append(command)
                writer.writerows([not_matched]) # THE PROBLEM LINE OF CODE
            if command in static_patterns:
                matched_static_pattern.append(command)
                
all_processes = len(commands)
exclude_dynamic = len(matched_dynamic_pattern)
exclude_static = len(matched_static_pattern)

print(all_processes - exclude_dynamic - exclude_static)
print('Results —', len(not_matched))
print(type(not_matched))
```

UPD:
I found a new solution:

```
with open('results1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outFile:
    for r in not_matched:
        outFile.write(r + "\n")
outFile.close()
```

But the problem is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wor77.png

Comment: You're creating a list called `not_matched` and you keep adding values to that list with `.append()` and on the "problem line" you write that list as a row to your .csv, so it makes sense that every time you write it, you're writing a longer line. Why do you keep adding to it?

Comment: So, how to change the code, so it will write a new line in one column?

Comment: Your updated solution probably does not work because the command lines that you are putting into the CSV file contain whitespace between command and arguments, and these are being treated as field separators by calc. That's why you need to use the CSV writer so that the fields are properly quoted. Since you have a single column, why do you need to use CSV at all?

Comment: I have a lot of columns in processes.csv and I'm using 
```reader = csv.DictReader(t1, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        commands.add(row['Command Line'])``` 
To take needed column for future manipulation with data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code accumulates non-matching commands in the `not_matched` list. However, the entire contents of that list are dumped to the CSV file each time a non-matching command is identified. To fix replace:

```
writer.writerows([not_matched]) # THE PROBLEM LINE OF CODE
```

with

```
writer.writerow([command])      # N.B. writerow, not writerows
```

Alternatively write the `not_matched` list to the CSV file in one go after the `for` loop terminates:

```
with open('results1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for command in commands:
        if command.startswith('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type') or command.startswith('"C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Teams\\current\\Teams.exe" --type'):
            matched_dynamic_pattern.append(command)
        else:
            if command not in static_patterns:
                not_matched.append([command])
            else:
                matched_static_pattern.append(command)
    writer.writerows([not_matched])    # write all non-matched commands in one go
```

Notice also that `if command in static_patterns:` can simply be replaced with `else:`.

Comment: It writes each value in separate new columns - https://i.imgur.com/dMupcpJ.png

Comment: I edited the main post with my new solution, but it didn't work too as I need.

Comment: @test_qweqwe: I assume that you tried the second version of my solution. `writer.writerows()` actually needs a list of lists. I've fixed the problem, the corrected line is `not_matched.append([command])`

Comment: I have the same results: i.imgur.com/dMupcpJ.png

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me!

```
with open('results1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    rows = zip(not_matched)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
outFile.close()
```